# Building apps on SLOW INTERNET, is that possible?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I used to try coding at my college (android studio) which had a terrible internet architecture and it wouldn't load.

What I want to know: **Is it possible for me to code on a bad/low internet (since I'll be on a farm) and still be fine?**

I'd be using VS Code + Flutter and probably Node or .Net for the project.

*by bad/slow internet I mean Satellite Internet - a really slow one.

Comment: Yes, you can without too much trouble. I do

Comment: For development wouldn't it all just be on your local machine? Go for it.

Comment: You might want to download the flutter docs before you go but besides that you should be.